# CommerceCloud - Navigation category visible for Registered users only

Tags: commerce-cloud, e-commerce

I'm trying to set up a category called "Category 1" which will only be visible for logged in users.

The only way I can think of this working is with Customer Groups, however, I can't see any options to set customer groups in the category edit settings.

Looking forward to hearing from someone on how to achieve this!

Comment: Hello damodamodamo, I suggest you edit your question given Commerce Cloud became its own beast (is it about B2C, B2B Classic, B2B Lightning, or even B2B2C)?

Answer (score 0):

There's no out-of-the-box feature available for this. You can use customer groups, but a dummy promotion will have to be set up to work around caching.

And there is no field on categories; you will have to create this yourself ( and do some development).